# Android square LinearLayout not showing content

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to display a square LinearLayout on my app, and I have created a custom class which extends LinearLayout, so that it´s square:

```
public class SquareLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public SquareLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareLinearLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, final int oldw, final int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, w, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```

Then, on the layout I add the linear layout and put a button inside it, for example, the problem is that although the layout works and is showed (if you set its background to any color it is visible), the elements inside the layout are not shown,as if it was empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.javierd.iifym.MainActivity">

    <com.javierd.iifym.SquareLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CaloriesLayout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/macronutrientsTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:background="#ff0000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Test"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </com.javierd.iifym.SquareLinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/macronutrientsTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin">

        <!-- IRRELEVANT CONTENT THAT FILLS THE SCREEN -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Could somebody help me to fix the issue?? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MikeM. okay, now the elements are showed but it looks like the Layout had different dimensions of what it has, as the elements are not centered and if you put a button and set weight and height to match_parent, it exceeds the layout and it is not fully showed: http://imgur.com/n4zg2S4

Comment: If you call the `super` method, you can use `heightMeasureSpec` for both arguments, and omit the `setMeasuredDimension()` call, but keep in mind that that's always going to square it up to the height, obviously. If you instead set the dimensions yourself without the `super` call, then you need to handle calling `measure()` on each child `View` yourself, as well, which is why the child `View`s weren't showing before, as they never had dimensions set, and ended up 0 by 0.

Comment: Okay, now it works perfectly.
Thanks a lot for your help and information!!